# What is the difference between /Applications and /Users/username/Applications?

Tags: macos, filesystems

The /Applications folder is what is displayed in finder, and recently due to some unknown problem all the items in my Users/username/Applications folder were replaced by "Chrome Apps.localized" but it has posed no problems to me. So my question is, what is the difference? Why does Users/username/Applications exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Mac can have multiple user accounts — imagine a family computer. The `Applications` folder in your home folder is meant for applications you don't want to share with other users.

`~/Applications` doesn't exist by default. It was created by you or an application you installed.

Comment: This is why some installers ask if you want to install a program for all users or not: to decide which of these folders to install into.